# Jqgrid Header text is overlapped in IE10

Tags: jqgrid, header, internet-explorer-10, overlap

I use Jqgrid in my MVC project. Because the view has many column, not all column are showned in screen same time. There is horizon scrollbar to allow user see an others columns. Page size is 20.

But, when user use mouse to scroll. The header text is disappeared.  This issue is occur only in IE10.

More information, if i press next page, the current header text is shown, but, an others header text disappear.

I also refer to this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1990281.aspx?Jqgrid+Header+text+is+overlapped+in+IE10 but cannot resolve.

Anyone has idea for this?

Thank you

Update:
I fake it by using this code:
$(function () {
            $("#gview_" + viewId + "*top").scroll(function () {
                //// This code fixes issue: headers disappear in jqgrid view when the view has horizontal scrollbar
                $(".ui-jqgrid-htable").css('background-color', 'rgb(66, 139, 202)');
                var headers = $("div[id*='jqgh*" + viewId + "']");
                if (headers != null && headers.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                        var header = headers[i];
                        //// Just reset text
                        header.innerText = header.innerText;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to this issue described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305317/435280

And as reported bug in IE 10:
[IE 10 elements with relative position disappearing when scrolling in parent element on Windows 7](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/817099/ie-10-elements-with-relative-position-disappearing-when-scrolling-in-parent-element-on-windows-7)

The only proposed resolution from MS was to upgrade to IE11 which doesn't really solve the problem if trying to support IE10 users.